# The best practice for creating a text file reader on android?

Tags: android

I want to create an app that reads and displays a big text file, so basically, it's a text file reader. There is something specific with the reader is that I would like to show a background image with the text. When the text scrolls, the image moves along with it.

I wondered what is the best practice for this? `TextView`? `WebView`? Or using `SurficeView` to draw the text/animation directly?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommand a `WebView`. But this would be easier if you already save the large Text as a HTML-Page. You can then use the [loadURL()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29)-method to show you'r HTML-File (i guess this is for the help-page?)